# How to manage the object_detection package dependency when distributing a python package?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm working in a project that uses the object-detection module in TensorFlow Models repo. I want to know the best way to install/manage only the object_detection module. Currently, I'm using github submodule with TF Models, but to distribute my code, I'd prefer not to bundle the whole TF Models repo, just the object_detection module.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be better off just copying the code you want, then.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll consider doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would recommend is to keep using the project as a git submodule since the `object_detection` module depends on the `official` package that is outside `research` dir. Also, at this moment there is no updated version of `object_detection` on pip.

If you really want to use only the parts that you need, you can follow as @Alexandre Passos mentioned.

You can add a Makefile to help you distribute your package, and adding a `setup.py` to specify other dependencies and to make your package distributable.

The Makefile should look something like this:

```sh
init:
    git submodule update --init --progress
    cd models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
    cd models/research && python setup.py install 
    cd models/research/slim && python setup.py install 
    # Install your package
    pip install -e .
```